# Cannot install bigmemory library in R 2.15.2 Windows

Tags: r, bigdata, r-bigmemory

I'm doing some analysis that requires me to compute a distance matrix (Euclidean for now, likely Mahalanobis later) from a 7000x182 array that will result in a 7000x7000 matrix (assuming I take the upper part of the matrix, too).

```
z <- as.matrix(dist(training.data[1:7000,], diag=TRUE, upper=TRUE))
```

The problem I'm running into is that I keep getting the "cannot allocate vector..." warning.  I've read up enough to know that R can't allocate enough contiguous memory on my PC to perform the action.  My PC has 3GB of RAM, and despite my best efforts or rm()'ing objects, using gc(), increasing my memory allocation to R through memory.limit(size=####), it doesn't work.

I like what I've read about the bigmemory library; however, when I attempt to install it I get a warning that it's not available on R 2.15.2.  Am I missing something here?  Is there a way around this?  I've read about some other R tools for managing big data, but none seem apropros to my task like bigmemory.

Comment: what OS?  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html points out that a Windows binary is not available and suggests that you compile from source. If you have the development tools installed (google "Rtools") then `install.packages("bigmemory",type="source")` should work ...

Comment: I apologize.  I thought I typed Windows XP SP3 in my posting.  Oops!  I did see that bit in the bigmemory documentation.  I just never had to do that.  I use Linux at home, so I never ran into the issue.  I'll try tomorrow at work.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so I tried downloading the latest .exe for RTools. Unfortunately, since my work laptop is basically locked down by IT, I couldn't edit the path to include my R\bin directory. Nonetheless, I downloaded the tarball for bigmemory and attempted to `RCMD --build bigmemory_4.4.3.tar.gz`.  I got the error that it's a UNIX-Only package.  ANy thoughts?  Does RCMD work without Rtools?

Comment: Don't know.  Ask maintainers?

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with bigmemory on windows before, and it seems like the only R version that I can use it on is 2.15.3 (it should install easily with a standard call to install.packages).  After the upgrade to R 3.0.x, it seems like bigmemory support for windows is "temporarily suspended" (see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/NEWS).  I was also never able to get it to work on R 2.15.2 or earlier either; I always ran into errors like the ones you mentioned.

My solution has been to have R 2.15.3 and the most recent version of R both installed on my windows machine.  I use R 2.15.3 for bigmemory and switch back to R 3.1.0 when not using it.  It's a pain, but bigmemory is worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
install.packages(c("BH","biglm"))
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github('kaneplusplus/bigmemory')
library(bigmemory)
```

PS you can also install `library(Rdsm)` on Windows using

```
devtools::install_github('tomwenseleers/Rdsm')
library(Rdsm)
```